# What is the correct notation for defining norms in measure spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, normed-spaces

For a function $f \in L_2(R)$, we can define its norm as 
$$ \|f\|_2^2 = \int f^2(x) dx $$

If I use a different measure $\mu$, I can in turn define the norm as 
$$ \|f\|_2^2 = \int f^2(x) \mu (x) dx $$ or even as 
$$\|f\|_2^2  = \int f^2(x) d\mu $$

In what I'm writing, I need to flip back and forth between the norm that uses the uniform measure and the one that uses $\mu$. Moreover, I will often use $p$-norms for some specific value of $p$ rather than the $2$-norm.

> Is there a standard notation to indicate which measure I'm using, or
>   do I have to do something painful like  $\|f\|_{2, \mu}$, which could
>   be confused with $\|f\|_{a,b}$, or $\|f\|_2^\mu$, which gets confused
>   with raising the norm to a power.

Comment: The notation I'm familiar with would be $\|\cdot\|_{L^2(\Bbb R, \mu)}$, as opposed to $\|\cdot\|_{L^2(\Bbb R, \lambda)}$ or $\|\cdot\|_{L^p(\Bbb R, \mu)}$. One might omit $\Bbb R$ if it's fixed througout.

Comment: So then it would be $\| \cdot \|_{L^p(\mu)}$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I've used and seen used when ambiguity is a concern (if, in addition, only a single measure is considered, the $L$ notation is omitted completely, leaving $\|\cdot\|_p$, but I take it that's not the case here).

Comment: Thank you. If no one introduces a notation I'm not familiar with, I will.